# JS - Attach string-value to a constructer call

Tags: javascript, google-api

I use the google virtual keyboard in my project. To initialize the keyboard, I run the following script:

```
google.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "keyboard"
});
function onLoad() {
    console.log(lang);
    var kbd = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard(
        [google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.GERMAN],
        ['input1']);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

But I want to replace `GERMAN` with a individual String. But how is this possible? I have defined a variable `var lang = SWEDISH` and tried the following:

```
function onLoad() {
    console.log(lang);
    var kbd = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard(
        [google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode.lang],
        ['input1']);
}
```

But this results in the following error-message: `uncaught undefined is not a supported layout.`

Any Idea, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
google.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "keyboard"
});
function onLoad() {
    console.log(lang);
    var kbd = new google.elements.keyboard.Keyboard(
        [google.elements.keyboard.LayoutCode[lang]],
        ['input1']);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

more info: [Google Developers: Virtual Keyboard](https://developers.google.com/virtual-keyboard/v1/getting_started#enum)